# Resultados se duplican en consulta mysql

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Estoy tratando de hacer un autocomplete con php/mysql y js pero al hacer la siguiente consulta

Me duplica los resultados en el input

[image: resultado]

Alguna idea de porque

---

```
if (isset($_GET['term'])){
include("../../config/db.php");
include("../../config/conexion.php");
$return_arr = array();

if ($con)
{
    $fetch = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM porteadores, camiones
    where porteadores.ruc_porteador=camiones.id_porteador_camion  
    and id_porteador like '%" . mysqli_real_escape_string($con,($_GET['term'])) . "%' LIMIT 0 ,50");        

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($fetch)) {
        $id_porteador=$row['id_porteador'];
        $row_array['value'] = $row['id_porteador'];
        $row_array['id_porteador']=$id_porteador;
        $row_array['nombre_porteador']=$row['nombre_porteador'];
        $row_array['nombre_porteador2']=$row['nombre_porteador'];
        $row_array['ruc_porteador']=$row['ruc_porteador'];
        $row_array['ruc_porteador2']=$row['ruc_porteador'];
        $row_array['direccion_porteador']=$row['direccion_porteador'];
        $row_array['provincia_porteador']=$row['provincia_porteador'];
        $row_array['departamento_porteador']=$row['departamento_porteador'];
        $row_array['pais_porteador']=$row['pais_porteador'];
        $row_array['direccion_porteador2']=$row['direccion_porteador'];
        $row_array['provincia_porteador2']=$row['provincia_porteador'];
        $row_array['departamento_porteador2']=$row['departamento_porteador'];
        $row_array['pais_porteador2']=$row['pais_porteador'];
        $row_array['cdtransporte_porteador']=$row['cdtransporte_porteador'];
        $row_array['resolucion_porteador']=$row['resolucion_porteador'];
        $row_array['poliza_porteador']=$row['poliza_porteador'];
        $row_array['id_porteador_camion']=$row['marca_camion'];
        array_push($return_arr,$row_array);
    }       
}
mysqli_close($con);
    echo json_encode($return_arr);

}
```

}

---

Acabo de descubrir que no los duplicado, mas bien me lista los items que tienen esa id almacenada en una columna osea, hay que 3 items con el id 12 que le pertenece a una categoria 1 con la 13 y 1 con la 10.

No entiendo a que se deba si estoy haciendo bien la consulta, agradeceria su apoyo.

Comment: No uses el área de respuestas para aclaraciones, puedes pulsar en [edit] y agregar  a la pregunta original lo que haga falta. Si revisas bien el código verás que en el `while`  metes datos repetidos en el array, es posible que por eso tengas duplicados.

Answer (score 0):

Si entendí bien, quieres un campo autocompletado para el `id_porteador`, en ese caso no debes usar como SQL una donde haces un join con `camiones`, ya que cada `id_porteador` va a aparecer tantas veces en el array como camiones tenga asociado.

Para conseguir lo que buscas usa diferentes SQL, una para cada caso, si usas esa SQL para otro listado no la reutilices para esto, usa una específica sobre la tabla `porteadores`, por ejemplo:

```
$fetch = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM porteadores
where id_porteador like '%" . mysqli_real_escape_string($con,($_GET['term'])) . "%' LIMIT 0 ,50");        

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($fetch)) {
    $id_porteador=$row['id_porteador'];
    $row_array['value'] = $row['id_porteador'];
    $row_array['id_porteador']=$id_porteador;
    $row_array['nombre_porteador']=$row['nombre_porteador'];

    array_push($return_arr,$row_array);
}
```

Comment: Roberto, antes de nada agradecerte por haber respondido.
Probare lo recomendado y te comento,
Gracias